# How can I add components dynamically to a container in specific order in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I am creating a UI dynamically from a json object. I will like to add components dynamically to a container according to a specific sequence. I have tried to use

```
Container cat = new Container();
cat.add(i,comp)
```

where i is an integer index and comp is a component. I get an error that layout does not accept index parameter. I have tied with BoxLayout and FlowLayout but something. So is this method signature wrong ab initio o what? What is the right way to add components in a given order dynamically?

Comment: This version of add maps to the constraint parameter `add(Object, Component)` due to autoboxing the offset is turned into an object which doesn't fit here... As Diamond said `addComponent(int, Component)` will accept an offset. Notice that by default all methods add to the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Try adding at a specific location and if that fails, add normally as the last component
try {

    cat.addComponent(i, comp);

} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {

    cat.add(comp);

}
```